# how to implement a interface to keep track of runtime of each sub-sections and also the total run time of the section in python

Tags: python, timer, time-tracking

is there any one know about: how to design a interface in python so that for the caller, it can track where time is being spent between two points in a piece of code?

For example: if we have several pieces of code we labeled them as A, B, C, D, so how could we track the runtime of these pieces and also about the runtime of the total piece of code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like something that you could make good use of a decorator for something like the [entryExit decorator](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=240808) could log the time spent inside each decorated function:

```
class entryExit(object):

    def __init__(self, f):
        self.f = f

    def __call__(self):
        print "Entering", self.f.__name__
        self.f()
        print "Exited", self.f.__name__

@entryExit
def func1():
    print "inside func1()"

@entryExit
def func2():
    print "inside func2()"
```

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** Now with function/method decorator support

I've done something like:

```
import timeit
from collections import OrderedDict


class TimeMarkContextManager(object):
    def __init__(self, mgr, key):
        self.mgr = mgr
        self.key = key

    def __enter__(self):
        self.mgr.mark("%s.start" % self.key)

    def __exit__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.mgr.mark("%s.stop" % self.key)

class TimeMark(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.marks = OrderedDict()

    def mark(self, key):
        self.marks[key] = timeit.default_timer()

    def manager(self, key):
        return TimeMarkContextManager(self, key)

    def pprint(self):
        base = self.marks.values()[0]
        last = None
        for (k,v) in self.marks.iteritems():
            delta_base = "%.3f" % (v - base)
            delta_last = "%.3f" % (v - last) if last is not None else "---"
            print("%-20s  %8s  %8s" % (k, delta_base, delta_last))
            last = v

def TimeMe(mgr, key=None):
    def TimeDeco(f):
        def func_wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            k = f.__name__ if key is None else key
            mgr.mark("%s.start" % k)
            rv = f(*args, **kwargs)
            mgr.mark("%s.stop"  % k)
            return rv
        return func_wrapper
    return TimeDeco
```

Which you could then use as follows:

```
import time                 # Only required for time.sleep()

tm = TimeMark()             # Initialize the TimeMark object

@TimeMe(tm)                 # Decorate a function, don't give it a special key
def sleep_four():           #  (it will use the function name as a key)
    time.sleep(4)

@TimeMe(tm, "sleep-five")   # Decorate a function, override the default tag
def sleep_five():
    time.sleep(5)

tm.mark("start")            # Create a mark called "start"
time.sleep(2)

# Use a context manager to time a block
with tm.manager("sleep-thirty"):
    time.sleep(10)
    time.sleep(10)
    time.sleep(10)

time.sleep(2)

sleep_four()                # Call the sleep_four function.
                            #   It'll show up as "sleep_four" (note underscore)
sleep_five()                # Call the sleep_five function.
                            #   It'll show up as "sleep-five" (note hyphen)

tm.mark("end")              # Create a mark called "stop"

tm.pprint()                 # Print a list of timemarks
```

Which outputs:

```
start                    0.000       ---
sleep-thirty.start       1.999     1.999
sleep-thirty.stop       32.001    30.002
sleep_four.start        34.001     2.000
sleep_four.stop         38.001     4.000
sleep-five.start        38.001     0.000
sleep-five.stop         43.002     5.000
end                     43.002     0.000
```

The first column is the specified key, the second column is the time delta since the first mark was set, the third column is the time delta since the previous mark.

And now that I see Steve Barnes' answer, adding decorator support wouldn't be a very nice complement.